How to install pipenv in Ubuntu 24.04?
I would like to install pipenv in Ubuntu 24.04, however, I can't. Below are the commands I have tried. How do I overcome these roadblocks? It used to be quite straight-forward in previous Ubuntu versions.
$ sudo apt install python3-pip

$ python3 -m pip install --user pipenv
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

$ sudo apt install pipx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-venv : Depends: python3 (= 3.12.3-0ubuntu1) but 3.12.3-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
$ sudo apt search pipx
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
pipx/noble 1.4.3-1 all
  execute binaries from Python packages in isolated environments

Update:
According to /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv, it is recommended to let Debian's package managers manage Python packages in /usr/lib/ and /usr/share/. Consequently, python applications and library modules that a user want to install should be done in a a virtual environment, so as to not conflict with the python packages that are already installed by the system/distribution/OS.
In this case, to install pipenv I should not do:
$ pip install --user pipenv

but I should instead do:
$ mkdir -p ~/.venvs
$ python3 -m venv ~/.venvs/pipenv
$ ~/.venvs/pipenv/bin/python -m pip install pipenv

To run pipenv on a terminal, I have to type the long command:
$ ~/.venvs/pipenv/bin/pipenv [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

or I can type pipenv on a termial after creating a soft link of ~/.venvs/pipenv/bin/pipenv into ~/.local/bin:
$ ls -la ~/.local/bin
total 2952
drwxrwxr-x 1 user user    4096 Dec  8 04:35 .
drwx------ 4 user user    4096 Dec  8 04:35 ..
$ ln -s ~/.venvs/pipenv/bin/pipenv ~/.local/bin
$ ls -la ~/.local/bin
total 2952
drwxrwxr-x 1 user user    4096 Dec  9 00:44 .
drwx------ 4 user user    4096 Dec  8 04:35 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user      37 Dec  9 00:44 pipenv -> /home/user/.venvs/pipenv/bin/pipenv
$ pipenv [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Running pipenv from a virtual environment (like shown below) seems  pointless since the purpose of using pipenv is to mitigate the above mentioned entirely by installing python applications and library-modules in virtual environments with the necessary dependencies.
$ source ~/.venvs/pipenv/bin/activate
(pipenv) $ pipenv [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Courtesy Notice:
Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment,  so it will automatically use that environment, instead of  creating its own for any project. You 
can set
PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create  its own instead.
You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.

From my past experience of running the command
$ python3 -m pip install --user pipenv

in Ubuntu 22.04 and earlier, I do not recall ever corrupting the system's python packages. Moreover, the option of --user  avoided the above mentioned conflict.
Given that the purpose of pipenv is to install python apps and libraries with their dependencies into unique virtual environments, and using --user option installs to the Python user install directory typically ~/.local/, will I break any system python packages by simply installing pipenv with:
$ python3 -m pip install --user --break-system-packages pipenv

This command line is simpler to implement than the tedious installation process mentioned in my updated section.
pip3 install -h states that the option

--break-system-packages     Allow pip to modify an EXTERNALLY-MANAGED Python installation

and does not give much details as to what it does or does not do. Consequently, I am posting my question and hoping to better understand the ever evolving Python ecosystem. Is the --user option now recognized to be unable to avoid package conflicts and I should totally avoid using it?

I see python-venv in your output, I see pipx, I see python3-pip. How confusing. You have one of them installed already, are you trying to remove it? You have a package manager error, are you asking how to fix it? Please edit your question to specify exactly what you want help with.
